# How to optically center two labels nativescript

Tags: layout, nativescript

I have two labels in a grid layout like so

```
<GridLayout columns="*, *" rows="auto, auto" row="1" >

            <Label col="0" text="{{ user.userData.firstName }}"  style="text-align: right;"/>
            <Label col="1" text="{{ user.userData.lastName }}"  style="text-align: left;"/>
            <Label text="&#xf040;" class="fontAwesome"/>             
 </GridLayout>
```

I want to center the user name and last name property optically. Right now the text is aligned with the center between the words. I would like it to be that the center would be the actual center regardless of the length of the first name or last name.

I have the two fields separate because I Need to style them separately. An answer that leads to one Label but with the firstname and second name given separate style would be cool as well since I can't imagine how to do that either.

Edit:

```
<Label>
              <Label.formattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                  <FormattedString.spans>
                    <Span text="{{ user.userData.firstName }}"fontSize="20"/>
                    <Span text="{{ user.userData.lastName }}" />
                  </FormattedString.spans>
                </FormattedString>
              </Label.formattedText>
            </Label>
```

I made a formatted string based on a suggestion. The properties have to be added manually and not with a css class.

Comment: I just made a formatted string however the css classes that I applied to the individual strings before don't seem to get applied to the spans. I did it via xml. See original post.

Comment: Oh i got it to work All the attributes have to be applied directly. Since Span does not inherit from the view class it does not register the css classes. You can post your  comment as an answer with the information and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one string but have it formatted differently using FormattedString class.